# PHP: Sort emails by domain

Tags: php, arrays, function, sorting, explode

This function works perfectly to sort a list alphabetically and clean all doubles.

```
function cleanMyList($myFile)
{
    $myTextFile=file_get_contents($myFile);
    $myArray=explode("\r\n",$myTextFile);
    $myArray=array_unique($myArray);
    sort($myArray);
    $myTextFile=implode("\r\n",$myArray);
    return $myTextFile;
}   
echo '<pre>'.cleanMyList('emails.txt').'</pre>';
exit;
```

This script works just fine but now what I want to do is sort it again by email provider (in other words: by domain) so the list would be sorted twice, First alphabetically and then resort it by email provider.

Here is an example:

emails.txt (before):

```
hezi-gangina@gmail.com
z-mkd@z-mkd.com
ein-leha-sikuy@yahoo.com
metrixheshbon@yahoo.com
metrixheshbon@yahoo.com
metrixheshbon@yahoo.com
stus-ve-thsiko@yandex.ua
tshiko-ve-diko@mail.ru
einlehasikuy@mertrix.com
hezi-gangina@gmail.com
einlehasikuy@mertrix.com
einlehasikuy@mertrix.com
einlehasikuy@mertrix.com
another-duplicate@email.com
another-duplicate@email.com
another-duplicate@email.com
another-duplicate@email.com
another-duplicate@email.com
```

email.txt after:

```
another-duplicate@email.com
ein-leha-sikuy@yahoo.com
einlehasikuy@mertrix.com
hezi-gangina@gmail.com
metrixheshbon@yahoo.com
stus-ve-thsiko@yandex.ua
tshiko-ve-diko@mail.ru
z-mkd@z-mkd.com
```

but I'm expecting to go one step further and get this (sort by domain) :

```
another-duplicate@email.com
hezi-gangina@gmail.com
tshiko-ve-diko@mail.ru
einlehasikuy@mertrix.com
ein-leha-sikuy@yahoo.com
metrixheshbon@yahoo.com
stus-ve-thsiko@yandex.ua
z-mkd@z-mkd.com
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? To sort it both ways?

Comment: Exactly! First sort it alphabetically and then sort it by email provider (domain)

Comment: This is what I mean did you made an attempt to solves this problem by yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

I just changed your code a little bit. First I grab your file with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) where I get ever line as an element in an array where I only take unique values with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). After this I sort your array with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) where I check if the domain is the same and if yes then I sort it by the alphabet.

```
<?php

    function cleanMyList($myFile) {
        $myArray = array_unique(file($myFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));

        usort($myArray, function($a, $b){
            preg_match_all("/(.*)@(.*)\./", $a, $m1);
            preg_match_all("/(.*)@(.*)\./", $b, $m2);

            if(($cmp = strcmp($m1[2][0], $m2[2][0])) == 0) {
                return strcmp($m1[1][0], $m2[1][0]);
            } else {
                return ($cmp < 0 ? -1 : 1);
            }

        });

        return $myTextFile = implode(PHP_EOL, $myArray);
    }

    echo "<pre>" . cleanMyList('emails.txt') . "</pre>";

?>
```

Output:

```
another-duplicate@email.com
hezi-gangina@gmail.com
tshiko-ve-diko@mail.ru
einlehasikuy@mertrix.com
ein-leha-sikuy@yahoo.com
metrixheshbon@yahoo.com
stus-ve-thsiko@yandex.ua
z-mkd@z-mkd.com
```

Comment: @Hezi-Gangina That's pretty clear since you don't have the privilege for this, but I want to know why it got downvoted so I can improve it

Comment: Thank you so much! Working perfectly! (I don't know who vote down) Your answer is accepted!

Answer (score 0):

$em="mynam@domain.com,second@second.com,
third@third.com,fourth@fourth.com";
Split the emails in two part

```
$ar=split(",",$em);
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($ar)) {
$ar2=split("@",$val);
echo $ar2[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $ar2[1];
echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Sort Array (Ascending Order), According to Value - asort()

```
 <?php
   asort($ar2);
?>
```

- asort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the value
- ksort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the key
- arsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the value
- krsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the key

Comment: you can use explode function instead  http://php.net/EXPLODE    , if you like my answer please don't forget to  mark it helpful. :)